# Typescript: Uncaught Type Error this.reduce is not a function at

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My code was working previously, displaying the data from an API correctly after using the reduce function.

I pulled my files from github on a new machine and suddenly I'm getting this error. Any help is greatly appreciated, as I've tried what I can to figure out what I've done wrong.

```
"ERROR TypeError: tickets.reduce is not a function
at SectionDashboardComponent.push../src/app/Sections/section- 
dashboard/section- 
dashboard.component.ts.SectionDashboardComponent.getTicketData (section-dashboard.component.ts:30)"
```

Here's the ts page where this error seems to be occurring:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { freshServiceService } from 
'src/app/Services/freshservice.service';
import { Ticket } from 'src/app/Domain/Ticket';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-section-dashboard',
 templateUrl: './section-dashboard.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./section-dashboard.component.css']
})
 export class SectionDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private _freshServiceService: freshServiceService) { }

private ticketCounts: number[];
private ticketResponders: string[];

ngOnInit() {
this._freshServiceService.fetchTickets().subscribe
(
  data =>
  {
    console.log(data);
    this.getTicketData(data);
  }
);
}

private getTicketData(tickets: Ticket[]): void {

const mappedTickets = tickets.reduce((x, y) => {
  {x[y.responder_name] = x[y.responder_name] + 1 || 1};
  return x;
}, []);

this.ticketResponders = Object.keys(mappedTickets);

this.ticketCounts = Object.values(mappedTickets);

console.log(this.ticketResponders);
console.log(this.ticketCounts);
}
}
```

Comment: probably tickets array is null

Comment: Didn't really even think about that since it was working previously, but that's what it was. For some reason the call I'm making is no longer working. Thanks, you saved me some time.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka that should normally say something like `Cannot read property 'reduce' of null`. In this case, it appears like `tickets` is not an array. It's unknown *what* it is, though - what's logged from  `console.log(data);`?